# Using java.util.Formatter as default formatter for slf4j

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, formatter

I currently have a custom log manager that internally uses `java.util.Formatter`. The main issue is that it's not very usable: everything in one file per application, no possibilities to add specific logs in a database, not able to send a mail, ...

So I would like to be able to increase the capabilities our logging system. After a few tests, Log4J is exactly what I need right now. But I would like to avoid the pain to re-change this again in the future, so I plan to use slf4j on top of Log4J.

Even if I'm ready to make a big search/replace in all my codebase to use slf4j, I'm not ready to check each log statement and reformat it to use the `{}` format of slf4j.

So my question is: how can I use slf4j interface and tell it that internally it should use a `java.util.Formatter` instead of its default one, preferably in one place (meaning not in each class or package)?

Notes: all answers speaking about performances or stating that I shouldn't use j.u.Formatter will be discarded: I need a pragmatic solution to my problem, not launching a debate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is patch http://bugzilla.slf4j.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116 which can be modified to suit your needs.
The discussion present there can also give further clarity on using util.Formatter.

Comment: This might help indeed, but isn't there a more straightforward solution?

Comment: Hmmmmm...Do you want someone to write it for you :) ... Try extending it the way they did it in Slfj Xlogger. Hope this helps

Comment: Well, as people say: a good programmer is a lazy developer :) Seriously, if there is already a direct solution, I'd prefer to take it. I'm a bit reluctant to maintain a local version of slf4j with just one or two changes, but if it's needed, well I'll do it.

Comment: It looks like no other answer is coming. So I'll accept yours. Thanks :-)